# Is it possible to pass variables like myfunction($var1="hi") in php?

Tags: php, function, variables

Is it possible, in php, to pass variables to functions like this:

```
function myfunction($var1="bar", $var2="foo"){
echo $var1 . $var2; 
}

myfunction($var2="bar");
```

and get the following output: barbar ?

Regards
Kristoffer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, named parameters are not supported in PHP.

An alternative is to pass an associative array of arguments and compare/merge against a set of defaults. Clunky, but works and is a pretty common pattern in some libraries and frameworks out there:

```
function myfunction($args = array()) {
    $defaults = array('var1' => 'bar', 'var2' => 'foo');
    extract(array_merge($defaults, $args));
    echo $var1 . $var2; 
}

myfunction(array('var2' => 'bar'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Named parameters are [not yet](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/27564/what-features-would-you-like-to-have-in-php) in PHP. There are a few workarounds to achieve it. JSON or array passing is one. But some PHP builtin functions use this method for spurios default values:

```
function yourfunction($var1=NULL, $var2=NULL) {
     $var1 or $var1 = "bar";
     $var2 or $var2 = "foo";
     $var3 or $var3 = "jip";

     echo $var1 . $var2;
}
```

Where the call syntax would be:

```
yourfunction(null, "baz");
```

So it's semantically more based on indexed parameters, not named ones. And the trick is having defered defaults in the function init code (much akin type checking etc.)

A more wacky option (only usable with scalars) are json or url parameters:

```
yourfunction("var2=bar;var3=xyz");
yourfunction('{"var2":"bar"}');    // very debatable
```

Comment: I don't think that short-circuiting syntax is going to work if a function accepts `false`, zero, blank or `NULL` as parameters. Also, are named parameters coming at all? I last heard a unanimous decision (by the team) against it.

Comment: @BoltClock: Obviously needs more fine-tuning for edge cases (approach unworkable for NULL). IIRC the feature has been booted because the parser again cannot easily support it. Yet programmers.SE has voted it up, so they'll better go implement it soon..